# Rustic - auto-complete gives intermediate dollar-values - not sure where to start loking

Tags: rust

Rustic (I think) keeps giving me what appears to be not-yet-filled-in completion.

When I type e.g. `env::va` I get suggestions that include `var(...)`, as expected, but when I hit return I end up with `env::var(${1:key})$0` in my text file, with point at the end of it. I'm assuming this is supposed to be a template that I tab through, filling in the values, but it's just left there as a literal string.

Not sure what the problem could be or even where to start digging into this besides taking my whole emacs config back to scratch and seeing if anything else is interfering with this - any suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn off `yasnippet` with `M-x yas-minor-mode`

If you are using company, remove `yasnippet` from the `company-backends`.

Comment: That's done the trick - thanks very much!